# Creating an abstract for two WPF Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, abstract

I am trying to reduce the code below so that I can call 'KeyHandler_F' from either window (KPIViewVAS, or KPIView) and execute changes to the window state with 'ToggleWindow'. The code below works but  is not DRY:

```
namespace KPI_Monitor_WPF.UI
{

class FullScreen
{
    public abstract class A<KPIViewVAS>
    {
        public abstract void KeyHandler_F(object sender, KeyEventArgs e, KPIViewVAS KVV);
        protected abstract void ToggleWindow(KPIViewVAS KVV);
    }

    public class B : A<KPIViewVAS>
    {
        public override void KeyHandler_F(object sender, KeyEventArgs e, KPIViewVAS KVV)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.F)
            {
                ToggleWindow(KVV);
            }
        }
        protected override void ToggleWindow(KPIViewVAS KVV)
        {
            switch (KVV.WindowState)
            {
                case (WindowState.Maximized):
                    {
                        KVV.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                        KVV.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.ToolWindow;
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    {
                        KVV.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
                        KVV.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public class C : A<KPIView>
    {
        public override void KeyHandler_F(object sender, KeyEventArgs e, KPIView KVV)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.F)
            {
                ToggleWindow(KVV);
            }
        }
        protected override void ToggleWindow(KPIView KVV)
        {
            switch (KVV.WindowState)
            {
                case (WindowState.Maximized):
                    {
                        KVV.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                        KVV.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.ToolWindow;
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    {
                        KVV.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
                        KVV.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

I started reducing the code with the example below however once I moved the commands for 'ToggleWindow' under the abstract class I got errors stating 'KVV.WindowState' could not be found:

```
class FullScreen
{
    public abstract class A<KPIViewVAS>
    {
        public virtual void KeyHandler_F(object sender, KeyEventArgs e, KPIViewVAS KVV) {
            if (e.Key == Key.F)
            {
                ToggleWindow(KVV);
            }
        }
        public virtual void ToggleWindow(KPIViewVAS KVV)
        {
            switch (KVV.WindowState)
            {
                case (WindowState.Maximized):
                    {
                        KVV.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                        KVV.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.ToolWindow;
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    {
                        KVV.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
                        KVV.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    }

    public class B : A<KPIViewVAS>
    {
        public override void KeyHandler_F(object sender, KeyEventArgs e, KPIViewVAS KVV)
        {

        }
        public override void ToggleWindow(KPIViewVAS KVV)
        {
        }
    }

    public class C : A<KPIView>
    {
        public override void KeyHandler_F(object sender, KeyEventArgs e, KPIView KVV)
        {
        }
        protected override void ToggleWindow(KPIView KVV)
        {
        }
    }

}
```

The windows 'KPIViewVAS' and 'KPIView' are below

```
    public partial class KPIViewVAS : Window
{

    public KPIViewVAS()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void KeyHandler_F(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        FullScreen.B switchScreen = new FullScreen.B();
        switchScreen.KeyHandler_F(sender, e, this);
    }
}

 public partial class KPIView : Window
{

    public KPIView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void KeyHandler_F(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        FullScreen.A switchScreen = new FullScreen.A();
        switchScreen.KeyHandler_F(sender, e, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: The basic problem is that the compiler doesn't have any information about `KPIViewVAS`. In your second example, that's not a type. It's a type _parameter_ and could be replaced by code using the generic type `A<KPIViewVAS>` by _any_ type. Unfortunately, you did not bother to provide a good [mcve] or enough other context to understand what the types you're using look like or how a generic class might look. It may be there's a base type you can use in a constraint to provide the info the compiler needs, or maybe you need to use `dynamic`, or maybe you just need to not make it generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Peter Duniho suggestion of using dynamic the code was reduced without any error. Any window can make use the code via

```
    private void KeyHandler_F(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        fullScreen.adjustScreen switchScreen = new fullScreen.adjustScreen();
        switchScreen.KeyHandler_F(sender, e, this);
    }
```

and the class was reduced to:

```
public class fullScreen
{
public class adjustScreen
    {
        public void KeyHandler_F(object sender, KeyEventArgs e, dynamic KVV)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.F)
            {
                ToggleWindow(KVV);
            }
        }
        private void ToggleWindow(dynamic KVV)
        {
            switch (KVV.WindowState)
            {
                case (WindowState.Maximized):
                    {
                        KVV.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                        KVV.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.ToolWindow;
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    {
                        KVV.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
                        KVV.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```